# Bigger Width for a specific item in UIStackview in Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, uistackview

There are 7 labels in 7 UIView and UIViews are inside StackView. I want just one view ( middle one) has more width than others because labels don't fit. Is there any way to do that?

[image: Views]

[image: TableView]

[image: Third SS]

When I change StackView from Fill Equally to Fill Proportionally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set fill proportionally in distribution field.

Comment: When I do that alignment will collapse. I added the screenshot of it.

Comment: So in this case you will be forced to add constraints to the UIStackView content.